# Use mousedown and drag to zoom image thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so basically I would like a user to be able to drag their mouse over a grid of images and for the image currently under the mouse to change to a larger size as the mouse moves.  If you're familiar with the zoom functionality on the OSX dock, this is pretty similar to what I want.  I am aware that I could easily accomplish this task with the 'mouseover' event, but I need a solution that can be implemented for touch and mouse inputs. As there is no mouseover equivalent for touch, I need to use mousedown and mouseup.  So far, this only works if the user clicks on an image, releases the mouse, and then clicks on another image.  He can't simply drag from one image to the next, with the images resizing along the way.
These are the two events, largeThumb and smallThumb are functions that resize the image.
    `$("img").on("mousedown" , largeThumb)
     $("img").on("mouseup", smallThumb)`
here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wg48Q/3/

Any suggestions?

Comment: What behavior do you want for touch screens?  Should the image size be toggled by tapping it or do you want the images to be resized as the user drags their finger across the images?

Comment: The image should be resized as the user drags their finger, like you said. When the finger leaves that image, it should return to its normal size.

Comment: Also, this is a future problem for me to solve...but I'm going to load the full size image when the finger is lifted up.  So if I drag over an image, then release, the full size image should load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any touch device at the moment, but this should work just as planned:

```
img {
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-out 0;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out 0;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-out:0;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-out 0;
}

img:hover {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Shu/2/

Comment: Thanks, but that sort of ignores the crux of the problem.  :)